# Uploading files to Jupyter running on VM VitualBox

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox, jupyter

Is it possible to upload a file (say a .pdf or .csv) saved in my hard disk into Jupyter running on VirtualBox?

Comment: Try the `upload` button on the right side of Juypter notebook.

Comment: The 'upload' button doesn't give access to my hard disk. It stays within the VM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

To begin with, your host PC mut have a shared folder with your VM (Explained elsewhere).

A method I do is to
First create a folder `myfolder` for the (.pdf or .csv) files.

Secondly, load the folder by: going to the created `myfolder`  --> right-click on the `myfolder` --> choose "Open in Terminal".

Thirdly, at the terminal it should look like this: `myfolder]$`. Then I type "jupyter notebook" as such: `[username@localhost myfolder]$ jupyter notebook` and hit ENTER. 
The folder should be opened and containing my .pdf or .csv files.